# The number of words (finite sequences) up to isomorphism

Tags: combinatorics

Let we have an alphabet $A = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ with $n$ elements. Any two words $W_1$ and $W_2$ with length $n$ in this alphabet we call isomorphic if there exists a permutation $P$ of alphabetic symbols such that $W_1 = P(W_2)$. Can it be proved that isomorphism defined in this way is an equivalence relation? If answer to previous question is "yes" let $Q$ be the quotient set of $A^n$ (set of all words with length $n$) of this relation. How to express the number of elements of $Q$ for any $n$?

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Oria said, the relation is an equivalence relation, but the number of elements in the quotient $Q$ is the number of partitions of the **set** $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$, that is called Bell Number (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set)

Comment: Number of partitions of 3 is 3 (https://oeis.org/A000041). But $Q$ for $A = \{0, 1, 2\}$ has classes isomorphic to words 000, 001, 010, 011, 012, which count is 5. Also for $A = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ the number of partitions is 5, but $Q$ contains classes isomorphic to (at least) 15 words: 0000, 0001, 0010, 0100, 1000, 1001, 1100, 0101, 1231, 1213, 1123, 2113, 2311, 2131, 0123. So number of $Q$ not equal to number of partitions.

Comment: @MikhailEfremov sorry, you're right. It wasn't the partitions of an integer, but the partitions of a Set, that is, the Bell Numbers

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

Every word can be permuted to itself with the identity permutation.
Every permutation is invertible so if $W_1 = P(W_2)$ there is another permutation $P'$ such that $P'(W_1) = W_2$.
if $W_1$ can be permuted to $W_2$ by permutation $P$ and $W_2$ can be permuted to $W_3$ by permutation $P'$ then $P'(P(W_1)) = W_3$.

So this is an equivalence relation.

Regarding the equivalence classes:

Two words are equivalent if they can be permuted to each other, or in better phrasing, if they contain the same letters.

For example if $n=2$ and $A = \{a,b\}$ then the classes are $\overline{[aa]} = \{aa\}$, $\overline{[bb]} = \{bb\}$, $\overline{[ab]} = \{ab,ba\}$.

So really, the number of equivalence classes (or number of elements in $Q$) is the answer to the question "how many words of length $n$ can we create from alphabet $A$, with repetition (we can use a letter more than once) and without order (ab = ba))." The answer to that question is $\binom{n + |A| -1}{n}$

Comment: $aa$ and $bb$ are isomorpic, so for case $|A| = 2$ we have only two elements in $Q$ (class isomorphic to $aa$ and class isomorphic to $ab$), not $\binom{3}{2}$ = 3

Comment: They are not isomorphic, there is no permutation that changes $aa$ to $bb$. Unless I misunderstood the question.

Comment: The permutation $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ of the alphabet $A = \{a, b\}$ changes $aa$ to $bb$ (and in this special case also $bb$ to $aa$).